# ScreenRecording a headless browser using xvfb with ffmpeg or jmf jar(java) shows distorted video in container, if the resolution greaterthan 1024x768

Tags: ffmpeg, docker-container, headless-browser, xvfb, screen-recording

I am getting a proper video output, if i used to record a screen resolution for about 1024x768(max) or lesser. but
whenever i used to increase the resolution like "1600x900 or 1920x1080 or greater than
1024x768 (approx.)", i am getting distorted video.

distorted image(frame of a video) with 1600x900 resolution
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iajzC.png

1600x900 video information : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yutDq.png

proper image(frame of a video) with 1024x768 resolution
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcUt1.png

1024x768 video information : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeaW7.png

I am using Xvfb & [both ffmpeg and jmf jar (either)] to record a headless browser inside docker container.

I am getting a proper output, if i used to screen record an actual display(monitor), I am facing this issue only when i record the display inside docker (specifically headless browser) by using x11grab.

To Start the Xvfb and ScreenRecording

> Xvfb :5 -screen 0 1600x900x16 &
>
> ffmpeg -nostdin -hide_banner -nostats -loglevel panic -video_size
> 1600x900 -framerate 30 -f x11grab -i :5 output.mp4 &

if i replaced 1600x900 with 1024x768 or lesser than this, it is providing a proper video without any distortion.

Am I missing anything??

Please help!

> Thanks for your time

Comment: Am working on something similar, how did you solve this, and is the project open source?

Comment: Also very intersted and working on the same, will report back if I find anything / make any progress

Comment: This may be relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499647/cant-run-xvfb-169-on-matrox-mga-g200 looks like it may have something to do with memory / aspect ratio

Comment: #found solution, 
we need to provide a proper depth of the screen, as i set 30 as depth for my x server.
it works @CeddyMuhoza